# Get event name in Nestjs and EventEmitter2 handler

Tags: nestjs, eventemitter

I have the following code:

```
  @OnEvent("**")
  public handleEverything(parentId: number): void {
    // @ts-expect-error this.envent
    console.log(this.event)
  }
```

I tried to get the event name by using the `this.event` but it returns `undefined`. Is there a way to get the event name inside the handler using Nestjs and EventEmitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is not possible. You can instead add a parameter to the payload when dispatching event and use it in the handler:

**Dispatching:**

```js
this.eventEmitter.emit('eventName', { type: 'eventType', others: 'others' });
```

**Listening:**

```js
@OnEvent("**")
public handleEverything(payload: any): void {
  if (payload.type === 'eventType') {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onAny` method of the event emitter. So your code may look as follows

```
this.eventEmitter
  .onAny((event: string | string[], ...values: any[]) => {
    // Handler code here
  });
```

So in this case you can handle both - event name and broadcasted message.